# Como pasar parametros a evento que no recibe?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Estoy tratando de pasarle el `objeto sender` a un evento que no recibe parametros, necesito el objeto sender para asi poder generar la informacion

Este es el evento que manda el objeto sender:

```
protected void DButton(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Pop", "showAndHide();", true);

            enable = true;
            DynamicButton();
        }
```

y este es el evento que quiero que reciba el objeto sender

```
protected void DynamicButton()
        {
            Button Btn_clic = (Button)sender;
            var name = Btn_clic.Text;

            List.ListUsers listArea = new List.ListUsers();
            List<Data.Area> Area = listArea.AreaList();

            List<Data.Area> ListOfEquiposOk = Area.Where(x => x.AREA == NECESITO EL EVENTO PARA CAMBIAR ESTE DATO ---> "ENG" && x.STANDBY == 0).ToList();

            List<Button> Botones = new List<Button>();

            var TeamFCH = ListOfEquiposOk.Select(x => x.TEAM).Distinct().ToList();
            foreach (var team in TeamFCH)
            {

                Button newButton = new Button();
                newButton.CommandName = "Btn" + Convert.ToString(team);
                newButton.ID = "Btn_" + Convert.ToString(team);
                newButton.Text = team;
                newButton.CommandArgument = "ENG";

                newButton.Click += new EventHandler(newButton_Click);

                pan1.Controls.Add(newButton);
                Botones = pan1.Controls.OfType<Button>().ToList();
                Botones.Add(newButton);

                newButton.CssClass = "btn-primary outline separate";

            }            
        }
```

y asi es como todo inicia

```
public partial class Dashboard : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        static bool enable = false;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {   
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                DynamicButton();
            }
            else if(enable)
            {
                DynamicButton();
            }    
        }
```

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta,lo siento. Que es `DButton` y cuando se le llama? Por que llamas a `DynamicButton` desde tantos sitios diferentes? Resumiendo,puedes explicar con palabras que es lo que quieres conseguir?

Comment: @Pikoh `DButton` se le llama desde el Dashboard, es un boton que inica dicho evento, y posteriormente inicia `DynamicButton` que inicia a crear los botones que traiga la lista de Area, para poder cambiar `x.AREA ==  "ENG"` ENG lo necesito reemplazar por el texto que tenga `DButton` en su evento sender

Comment: Y porque no haces que el metodo `DynamicButton` reciba un parametro `sender`? `DynamicButton(object sender)`

Comment: @EinerSantana si lo hago de esa manera me marca error en muchos lados y no se inicia el evento `DynamicButton`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aun sigo sin entender porque no haces que el metodo DynamicButton reciba el parametro sender.

```
void DynamicButton(object sender);
```

> @EinerSantana si lo hago de esa manera me marca error en muchos lados
>   y no se inicia el evento DynamicButton

Obviamente no porque tienes que pasarle el parametro sender. Si el metodo depende de ese parametro pues pasaselo en todos los lugares que lo requiera.

Pero si no quieres enviarle el `sender` entonces pasale el texto que esperas para generar el botton dinamicamente. Como solo necesitas el sender para obtener la propiedad `Text`:

```
protected void DynamicButton(string nombre = null)
{
   if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(nombre)) return;

   var name = nombre;
   //..
}

//..
DynamicButton("NombreButton");
```

La condición lo que hace es evitar que si envías un nombre vació pues que no genere el `Button`. Y agregandole el parámetro opcional no te daría error en todos lados como mencionaste.

Answer (score 0):

en .NET existe la convención de que los eventos se basen en este `delegate`

```
public delegate void EventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);
```

Como puedes ver, el evento `DynamicButton` que estás utilizando no cumple con dicha convención, simplemente cambia el método para que acepte los parámetros requeridos.

**EDICION**

Antes de que se me olvide, también existe:

```
 EventHandler<TEventArgs>
```

pero no es conforme con la CLS así que recomiendo utilzar el de arriba

Comment: si le agrego el object sender o el eventargs deja de funcionar todo

Comment: Tienes que modificar cada vez que llamas al evento y pasarle los parámetros, en el ejemplo lo llamas en los métodos `Page_Load` y `DButton` que son a su vez eventos. Puedes aprovechar los mismos parámetros que recibes o crear tu propio tipo `EventArgs`